# upsert:true with a Dotted _id Query

Tags: mongodb

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#mongodb30-upsert-id

According to this document the upsert does not go through because

"This restriction ensures that the order of fields embedded in the _id document is well-defined and not bound to the order specified in the query"

But if I slighlty modify the query as shown below, it inserts successfully.

Why is this allowed?

```
db.collection.update(
    {"_id.name": "Robert Frost", "_id.uid": 0},
    {"$set": {"categories": ["poet", "playwright"]}},
    {upsert: true}
)
```

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34189?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Comment: What was you original query that caused the error?

Comment: db.collection.update( { "_id.name": "Robert Frost", "_id.uid": 0 },
   { "categories": ["poet", "playwright"] },
   { upsert: true } )